Postgresql: From array of jsons to a single, id-indexed json
In a SQL function I have an array of jsonb in the format:
[{id: 1, name: John}, {id: 2, name: Jane}]

I would like to transorm this structure to a single jsonb using the ids as keys:
{
  1: {id: 1, name: John},
  2: {id: 2, name: Jane}
}


JSON doesn't support numeric keys, so those will actually be "1" and "2". Do you want to only select that, or update it in-place?

You can explode the array with jsonb_array_elements(), then re-aggregate to an object with jsonb_object_agg(). Demo at db<>fiddle:
select jsonb_object_agg(_element->>'id', _element)
from my_table
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(my_table.jdata) as _an(_element)
group by my_table.ctid




jsonb_object_agg




{"1": {"id": 1, "name": "John"}, "2": {"id": 2, "name": "Jane"}}


{"1": {"id": 1, "name": "John"}, "2": {"id": 2, "name": "Ted"}, "11": {"id": 11, "name": "Jane"}, "111": {"id": 111, "name": "Bob"}}



You can't use a JSON number as a key, which is why I used ->> accessor casting to text. Not knowing your primary key, I'm grouping by system column ctid because it's always present and unique, but you probably want your actual PK. The cross join lateral can be replaced with a single comma , but explicit join syntax is typically preferred over old, implicit style.
If you didn't want the actual id but rather the index in that array to be the new key, you can use with ordinality to get those:
select jsonb_object_agg(n::text, e)
from my_table 
   , jsonb_array_elements(jdata) with ordinality as elements(e,n)
group by my_table.ctid


Same, but as an update rather than a select:
update my_table set jdata=
(select jsonb_object_agg(e->>'id', e)
 from jsonb_array_elements(jdata) e )
returning jsonb_pretty(jdata);




jsonb_pretty




{    "1": {        "id": 1,        "name": "John"    },    "2": {        "id": 2,        "name": "Jane"    }}


{    "1": {        "id": 1,        "name": "John"    },    "2": {        "id": 2,        "name": "Ted"    },    "11": {        "id": 11,        "name": "Jane"    },    "111": {        "id": 111,        "name": "Bob"    }}



Note that jsonb array always keeps its original order as significant, but the resulting jsonb object will be freely reordered by PostgreSQL, based on keys.

cross join is preferred over comma-joins.

@Charlieface I know I'm in minority on that topic, hence the remark in the answer. I like their brevity when working with a single table feeding a bunch of SRFs so I don't mind occasionally giving bystanders some flashbacks of their 80's-00's SQL trauma. :)

@Charlieface That being said, I've edited the post to flip the narrative and left the ,-join as an extra, in the second example that can use the shorter syntax to accommodate the additional keywords. I figured it makes sense to open with the correct method and only mention the other syntax after that.

@Charlieface: Aside from personal preference and strong opinions, comma and CROSS JOIN are just two different, equally valid syntax variants, with subtly different roles, even. See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167217/3684
